# How to access the storyboard of an SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have created an SDK which includes a storyboard. In the storyboard there are 4-5 view controllers. How to access the storyboard of the SDK?

Here is my code:

```objc
- (void)openAppleInAppProvisionMain {
    // NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.digiTech.apple.applewalletNFI"];

    NSLog(@"Received from Main Kony Callback : %@", shManager.callBack);
    NSLog(@"Received from Main Kony Data : %@", shManager.dictResponse);
    NSLog(@"method is accessible in this way");

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"WalletMain" bundle:bundle];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CardsViewsController"];

    [AppleWallet performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(presentTheViewController:) withObject:vc waitUntilDone:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getCardsList" object:nil userInfo:shManager.dictResponse];
}

+ (void)presentTheViewController:(UIViewController *)vc {
    if(vc) {
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        // [KonyUIContext onCurrentFormControllerPresentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

In this way I am able to access this method and also all other methods in my sample app, but I'm not able to load the storyboard of the SDK to my sample app.

My storyboard settings are like this.

I have tried with the bundle changes but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your storyboard is not located within main app bundle.
You may try it in next way, where the `CardsViewsController` class is expected to be part of your SDK:

```
NSBundle *sdkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[CardsViewsController class]];
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"WalletMain" bundle:sdkBundle];
```

Comment: still not working , tried your solution. also tried some way to debug , while debugging inside the Xcode I can see the view controller but it is not showing on the device

Comment: please can someone help me in this